# How to get the ARN of an SSM Document in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, ssm

I have a CloudFormation template that creates an `AWS::Events::Rule` and an `AWS::SSM::Document`. I need to provide a list of `Targets` for the `SSM::Rule`, but each target expects an `ARN`:

```
mySSMDocument:
  Type: AWS::SSM::Document
  Properties:
    DocumentType: 'Command'
    Content:
      schemaVersion: '2.2'
      description: "Code that will be run on EC2"
      mainSteps:
        - action: "aws:runShellScript"
          name: runShellScript
          inputs:
            runCommand:
              - 'Some command to execute'
myEventRule:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    Description: "A description for the Rule."
    EventPattern: 
      source:
        - "aws.autoscaling"
      detail-type:
        - "EC2 Instance-terminate Lifecycle Action"
      detail:
        AutoScalingGroupName:
          - !Ref 'someAutoScalingGroupInThisTemplate'
    RoleArn: 'some role ARN'
    State: "ENABLED"
    Targets:
      - Id: "some-unique-id"
        Arn: <-- This is the value that I need to fill in.
        RunCommandParameters:
          RunCommandTargets:
            - Key: "tag: Name"
              Values:
                - 'The name of the EC2 machine'
```

I think that I need to replace the `<-- This is the value that I need to fill in.` with the `ARN` of `mySSMDocument`, but I don't see any way to retrieve this value from within the template itself. [The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-document.html) does not specify any `GetAtt` functionality on `SSM::Document` that allows to get the `ARN`. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ARN pattern of Document

> arn:${Partition}:ssm:${Region}:${Account}:document/${DocumentName}

example:

> arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:12345678912:document/demoooo

You can use `Ref` function to get name of document, then `Sub` to create final ARN

refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awssystemsmanager.html#awssystemsmanager-resources-for-iam-policies

Comment: Any reason to use `Join` instead of `Sub`? I see it being used everywhere while `Sub` is much more readable.

Comment: @TuanVA Can I give ARN pattern for package (which is created using distributor in system manager)? I tried but it is not accepting

Answer (score 7):

```
!Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:document/${mySSMDocument}
```

You can produce the [ARN format for `AWS::SSM::Document`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awssystemsmanager.html#awssystemsmanager-resources-for-iam-policies) using the [return Value for `AWS::SSM::Document`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-document.html#aws-resource-ssm-document-return-values), the [Pseudo Parameters for Partition, Region, and AccountId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html), and the [`Sub` intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)